# How to redirect in .htaccess for specific pattern URI

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I want my site to be redirected to products.php when someone hits the URL `mysite.com/products/sampeproductname/sampeproductid`. It should show the `products.php` file.

Now I've written code like below.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/products/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ products.php
```

It redirects all the URLS but I want it to be redirected only the URL structure similar to

```
mysite.com/products/iPhone-xr/10
```

Comment: 1. You don’t need to use a RewriteCond for this, RewriteRule can check on the path component of the URL directly. 2. Your regular expression does _not_ match the URL, and since it is negated, it then allows the rewrite by the following rule to happen. And that rule was written to match just _anything_.

Comment: Then how to write

Comment: Figure out the correct regular expression to match the URL format you want to target first of all. Tools like https://regex101.com/ can help with that (to a certain degree.)

Answer (score 0):

This should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?products/(\w+)/(\d+)$ /products.php?prdName=$1&prdId=$2 [END]
```

Whether `(\w+)` matches the product name in all cases depends on the actual character set you are using there which you did not specify in the question. You may have to adapt that to your needs.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: It shows 500 response. In apache error log it says "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

Comment: The rule above will not result in an endless rewriting loop. Either you did not implement that rule, but altered it or you have other rules in place the interfere here which you did not tell us about.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

 Options -Indexes`

This is what I have below those lines. Will it work if I put the code below this?.

Comment: I'd place it _above_ that rule, actually, since that rule is more specialized than the general fallback rule. I fail to see a rewriting loop though regardless of the order. You might want to add an ``[END]`` flag to that exsiting rule too, though.